# Open Graph Issues - Facebook

Tags: facebook-opengraph

Can anyone tell me why facebook doesn't pull the correct og tags from this [article](https://www.goaexperience.co.uk/blog/favourite-restaurants-in-north-goa)?

I have specified the `og:title` and `og:url` but all I get is this error when I fetch new scrape information

[Facebook og errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RLS0.png)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The error specifically tells you that you are missing the `og:image:url`?

Comment: Yes, although I have it in the code `<meta property="og:image" content="//assets.serenity.co.uk/38000-38999/38112/300x200.jpg">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an absolute URL with the protocol for the OG image:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://assets.serenity.co.uk/38000-38999/38112/300x200.jpg">
```

Also, the first `og:image` tag is this one in the source:

```
<meta property = "og:image" content = " " />
```

There are also several `og:title` tags in the source.

Comment: Ah it makes sense. Will push those changes then and will hopefully fix the errors. Thanks ! :)

Comment: don´t forget to refresh the url in the debugger